# jQuery - remove several classes

Tags: jquery

Is there a more efficient way to remove several unneeded classes from dom elements at once?

JS

```
$('.one').removeClass('one');
$('.two').removeClass('two');
$('.three').removeClass('three');
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Selecting more then one element separated by comma, Removing more then one class from element separated by space

```
$('.one, .two, .three').removeClass('one two three');
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/am2h4dnb/1/)

Comment: This solution works perfectly. To see the output in his demo you will have to right click on the html section and click on inspect element and you will see that the classes are no longer there

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to remove multiple classes from one element**, then separate classes by space.

```
http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

One or more space-separated classes to be removed from the class attribute of each matched element.
```

**If you want to remove different classes from different elements**, I think then it will be better to make an array and remove classes by iterating over it.

Comment: You can use a class selector on different elements. Do you have an example of when iterating through an array would be necessary?  A time I can think of is if you have to make a decision based on if the element contains that class. In this case he is just removing them.

Comment: @LarryLane: A time when the user will have to remove a large number of classes from set of different elements, for better performance. This `$('.one, .two, .three').removeClass('one two three');` will try to remove all three classes from every element, consider this with large number of classes ..